# Laravel 5.5 Routes order does not work

Tags: laravel, routes

I have these routes:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['ForLoggedIn']], function()
{

    //article actions
    Route::get ('blog/gallery', 'ContentController@showGallery');
    Route::get ('blog/import', 'ContentController@importArticles');
    Route::get ('blog/{article}/edit', 'ContentController@editArticle');
    Route::get ('blog/all', 'ContentController@allArticlesList');
    Route::get ('blog/add', 'ContentController@addArticle');
});

Route::get ('blog/{article}', 'ContentController@blogArticle');
```

Routes are supposed to consider the order right? A strange thing happens. 'blog/all' and 'blog/gallery' end up in the last ContentController@blogArticle. However, 'blog/add' works well.

How is that possible? I tried all the cache clearing I found. Any ideas what might be wrong? Thank you for any hints.

**Edit**: 
When I comment the last route, everything works ok.

Comment: what the result if u type php artisan route:list ?

Comment: I get a list of routes. The order is correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;DR: I don't know if this actually answers the question, but I was about to post my own question-answer when I ran into a similar problem and posted on GitHub to the laravel/framework project. Check out `$ route:list --sort` to see the actual list of routes in order of consideration.

```
// Handle the public
Route::resource('your-resource', YourResourceController::class, [
        'only' => [
            'index',
            'show'
        ]
    ])
    ->middleware(['web']);

// Put everything else behind a wall
Route::resource('your-resource, YourResourceController::class, [
        'except' => [
            'index',
            'show'
        ]
    ])
    ->middleware(['web', 'auth']);
```

Create (/create) ends up with show (/{your-resource}). `route:list` shows the following.

```
your-resource
your-resource
your-resource/create
your-resource/{your-resource}
```

Thereby hiding the "defect", which is that the interpretation order is really:

```
your-resource
your-resource
your-resource/{your-resource}
your-resource/create
```

Due to the ordering of the route blocks. Switching them fixes the problem:

```
// Put everything else behind a wall
Route::resource('your-resource, YourResourceController::class, [
        'except' => [
            'index',
            'show'
        ]
    ])
    ->middleware(['web', 'auth']);

// Handle the public
Route::resource('your-resource', YourResourceController::class, [
        'only' => [
            'index',
            'show'
        ]
    ])
    ->middleware(['web']);
```

Comment: Hi Josh, 'except' solved the problem. The order in the route:list was correct. Switching the order of the routes didn't help. It could get it worse, but not better :)  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to follow the laravel resouce routing.

if you are working in one controller you need to follow this order in your routes.

index ,create,store,show,edit,update,destroy

stated at https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/controllers .

try to place this routes

```
Route::get ('blog/add', 'ContentController@addArticle');
```

before

```
Route::get ('blog/{article}/edit', 'ContentController@editArticle');
```

Comment: Didn't help. I tried all combinations of order, but I can get max 2 of the routes working. With some combinations, nothing is working.

Answer (score 0):

In general laravel will find the route matches from top to bottom

So pls try following route:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['ForLoggedIn']], function()
{
    //article actions
    Route::get ('blog/gallery', 'ContentController@showGallery');
    Route::get ('blog/import', 'ContentController@importArticles');
    Route::get ('blog/all', 'ContentController@allArticlesList');
    Route::get ('blog/add', 'ContentController@addArt`enter code here`icle');
    Route::get ('blog/{article}/edit', 'ContentController@editArticle');
});
Route::get ('blog/{article}', 'ContentController@blogArticle');
```

Comment: Nothing. By changing the order of the routes I can get one of them working. I have no idea why this happens.